# Json objects saving as String rather than Object

Tags: java, json, oop, gson

I am saving and loading a hashmap using Json/Gson.

When I save the hashmap attributes with key String and Value EnumElement. For example:

```
private static enum Rank {
    BOSS;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    HashMap<Object, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();

    attributes.put("test", Rank.BOSS);

    //save json file here...


}
```

Then when loading the hashmap with json, and setting the map like this:

```
attributes = loadJson("path/savedAttributes");
```

Then the loaded map has changed the enum element of Rank.BOSS to a String "BOSS"

The result is now:

```
 "attributes": {
    "test": "BOSS",
 },
```

It is now a String.

How do I overcome this?

I want it to load as the enum element again not a string representation

Comment: If you need stronger typing than what can be inferred from the JSON itself, you will have to tell your JSON library about it. The easiest way would be to use a proper bean class instead of `Map<Object, Object>`. How else is it supposed to know that the key "test" is should contain this Enum?

Comment: @Thilo concept is a good one, I recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  Gson `TypeAdapterFactory` [here](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html)